# How to capture the Batch script error during a run in Github Actions workflow

Tags: batch-file, github-actions

When Batch script is run as a job from workflow it exits with errorlevel, but the overall job status gives success, instead of failure. How can I capture the error and get workflow status as failed.

Attaching snippets of the Github Action workflow yaml file

```
- name: Setup Release directory
  id: Release_directory
  run: .\\Compile_testsuite.bat
        
- name: Check on failures
  if: (${{ success() }} || ${{ failure() }}) && (${{ steps.Release_directory.outcome }} == 'failure')
  run: echo ${{steps.Release_directory.outcome}} #exit 1
```

Attaching the code snippet of the Batch script

```
@echo off
rem Get Current Path
set defaultPath=%CD%
set defaultPath=%defaultPath: =%

set /p version=<Version.txt
set ReleasePath=%defaultPath%\Release_%version%

set runPath=%ReleasePath%\run
set workloadsPath=%ReleasePath%\workloads
set commonPath=%workloadsPath%\common
set resultsPath=%ReleasePath%\results
echo %defaultPath%

if not exist %ReleasePath% mkdir %ReleasePath%
if not exist %runPath% mkdir %runPath%
if not exist %workloadsPath% mkdir %workloadsPath%
if not exist %resultsPath% mkdir %resultsPath%
if not exist %commonPath% mkdir %commonPath%

set Identifier=false

rem Iterate over directory
for /D %%w in (*) do (
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        set workloadPath=%defaultPath%\%%~nxw

        for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~nxw") DO ( 
            set var=%%a

            if "!var!" == "Excel" ( set "Identifier=true")
            if "!var!" == "Word" ( set "Identifier=true")
            if "!var!" == "Outlook" ( set "Identifier=true")
            if "!var!" == "Powerpoint" ( set "Identifier=true")
        )


        if "!Identifier!" == "true" (
            REM Print Workload path
            echo !workloadPath!
            cd !workloadPath!
            nuget install !workloadPath!\%%~nxw\packages.config -o !workloadPath!\packages\
            echo !workloadPath!\%%~nxw.sln
            msbuild !workloadPath!\%%~nxw.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"
            rem echo "ERROR_LEVEL" !errorlevel!
            if not !errorlevel! == 0 ( exit /B !errorlevel!)
            set exePath=!workloadPath!\%%~nxw\bin\Release\Executable

            if not exist !workloadsPath!\%%~nxw\bin mkdir !workloadsPath!\%%~nxw\bin
            if not exist !workloadsPath!\%%~nxw\input mkdir !workloadsPath!\%%~nxw\input
            copy !exePath! !workloadsPath!\%%~nxw\bin
            copy !workloadPath!\%%~nxw\bin\Release\input !workloadsPath!\%%~nxw\input

            cd %defaultPath%
        )
```

Output from the Workflow run in Github Actions
[image]

I'm trying to run build a vs code solution using **"msbuild"**. If the build is not successful, Batch script should terminate. So I have added if condition to check status of msbuild.
When I run the workflow, I'm trying to check the build of the solution, if build is successful, I need to run the application using next task.

Comment: If you are going to post code, it needs to be a [mcve]. You cannot post just part of a `for` loop and expect us to understand how it is working. It appears that your are using `exit /b !errorlevel!` as soon as one of your loops fails, but we have no idea what that exits, because you have not posted the rest of the batch file. For all we know, you just need to use `exit !errorlevel!`.

Comment: The if syntax seems wrong to me, try: `... ${{ steps.Release_directory.outcome == 'failure' }} )`

Comment: @Compo have added the part of the batch script

Comment: @Saikrishna, you have added more content, but still have not included any of the pertinent parts. Your use of `%%~nxw` is a definite indication that everything you've included is only part of a `for` loop command. Also you have not provided any information to show how you propagated the variables `Identifier`, `workloadsPath`, `exePath` and `defaultPath`. We have no idea where, when or how you are using delayed expansion, if any of that code is within a `call`ed label or script, etc. It is not possible for us to replicate your issue, unless we can match your code and your environment.

Comment: @Compo the basic idea is, I have to run a ms office application of vs in git actions. I'm checking the step of build, if it is completed successfully, then I wanted to run the application in next step. I have added rest of the code for batch script. I'm just checking the error of msbuild, that alone is of most importance.

Comment: Note that these are not Git actions, but rather Git*Hub* actions. The default runner is PowerShell (see https://github.community/t/bat-script-not-found/119234).

Comment: @Saikrishna, I have better indented your batch file code to show you and others that it is still not a [mcve]. Your `SetLocal` has no matching `EndLocal` and your parenthesized `For /D` loop has not been closed, _(it does not have a matched parenthesis)_. Your code therefore is incomplete, and will not work. We cannot help you, if you keep on deliberately omitting the content we require to determine the actions of the batch file, with respect to the success or failure message it may report. There is also a complete lack of doublequotes, in my quick estimate is within twenty six of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have directed the output to a new file, and checked for failure keyword in the file. If any error occurred, I will terminate the run in workflow.

Comment: I'd suggest that `github-actions` does not see `errorlevel` of the batch, but only detects whether the batch completed successfully or not. Perhaps you could try forcing a batch error by say, dividing a number by 0 or attempting to execute a non-existent program. I know nothing about `github-actions`, so it's really a shot in the dark.

Comment: You need to use `shell: cmd`, see my answer for more detail. It's way better than checking for some string in the output.

Answer (score 0):

> When Batch script is run as a job from workflow it exits with errorlevel, but the overall job status gives success, instead of failure.

Yes, this is in turn caused by the default shell in a GH Action being PowerShell Core, which doesn't return the `ERRORLEVEL` as the exit code from running a batch script.

As [can be read here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell), this behavior is by design. However, the proper way of fixing this, opposed to attempting to capture the output and parsing it, is to use `shell: cmd`, which will properly propagate the `ERRORLEVEL` from the batch file.

Here's an example script:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      # checkout the code
      - name: checkout-code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      # setup dotnet based on global.json
      - name: setup-dotnet
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      # build it, test it, pack it
      - name: Run dotnet build (release)
        # see issue #105
        # very important, since we use cmd scripts, the default is pwsh, and a bug prevents errorlevel to bubble
        shell: cmd
        run: ./build.cmd
```